# Java: DateTimeFormatter fail to parse time string when seconds and milliseconds are all 0s?

Tags: java, date, format, java-time, java-10

Basically, I am using the following code to parse string as LocalDateTime, which works fine most of the time.

```
DateTimeFormatter dtformatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS");
```

However, I encounter cases where the seconds and millseconds are `00000` and this is when the parser fails and print a `LocalDateTime` `2018-03-01T09:16` instead of `2018-03-01T09:16:00.000`.

```
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse("20180301091600000",dtformatter));
```

(Note that in my code, I have to parse string as `LocalDateTime`, do some comparison and then at the end, print `LocalDateTime` to csv)

How can I fix it to make it print `2018-03-01T09:16:00.000` instead of `2018-03-01T09:16` ?

FYI, I am using jdk10.

Comment: It was a bug in Java 8: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8031085. But it should be fixed in Java 9, so seeing it in Java 10 is surprising.

Comment: It seems the parser is fine, otherwise it would not print anything at all, other than a parse error. Your problem seems to be in the default format for printing a `LocalDateTime`. You should format your print as well.

Comment: Your code executes just fine on my Java 9.

Comment: @OleV.V. I'm using Java 10 it return `2018-03-01T09:16`

Comment: I get the same result on both Java 9 and 10, @YCF_L. It is also the result that I expected. BTW, mynameisJeFF, what makes you think you have a problem? `2018-03-01T09:16:00.000` is ISO 8601, but so is `2018-03-01T09:16`, so any API that accepts the former, I would expect it to accept the latter too. Try and see if you’re not all fine.

Comment: @OleV.V. why `20180301091600001` return `2018-03-01T09:16:00.001` but `20180301091600000` return `2018-03-01T00:00` why its not return `2018-03-01T00:00:00.000`

Comment: @YCF_L For brevity, I suppose (I didn’t design it). In `2018-03-01T00:00` it’s understood that the seconds and fraction of seconds are 0, so printing them is not needed. I think [Basil Bourque’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49971698/5772882) explains. BTW and for comparison, if you wanted to print the full precision of the `LocalDateTime` object, you would need `2018-03-01T00:00:00.000000000`.

Comment: @YCF_L Also remember that the `LocalDateTime` object doesn’t know (doesn’t remember) which string it was parsed from. It just holds a date and a time of day (with nanoseconds precision).

Comment: @OleV.V. ok I agree it is not a bug, but the OP want to get `2018-03-01T09:16:00.000` instead of `2018-03-01T09:16` so I think my solution is correct no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why it's not work, <s>it seems it is a **bug** because</s> when I use :

```
20180301091600001        result is      2018-03-01T09:16:00.001
----------------^                       -----------------^^^^^^
```

Also another test :

```
2018030100000000         result is      2018-03-01T00:00
--------^^^-----                        -----------^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It seems that the parser ignore the **seconds** and **millisecond** when it is zero, why?

The full explanation **why?**, is in the answer of [Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49971698/5558072).

---

## Solution

Here is a quick fix where you can use another formatter like this :

```
var result = LocalDateTime.parse("20180301091600000", dtformatter)
                .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSS"));
```

**Output**

```
2018-03-01T09:16:00:000
```

Comment: @mynameisJEFF no problem, I report it to open jdk so we can wait until they decide what is the problem

Comment: @YCF_L  Can you link to your bug report?

Comment: @BasilBourque I report it but I don't get any link, I think it take some time to be analyse and decide if it is a bug or not

Comment: @BasilBourque can you report it again please?

Comment: @YCF_L No, I do not believe this is a bug. See my Answer on this page.

Comment: In other words, @YCF_L your “temporary solution” is correct and more than a temporary solution, it is *the* solution.

Comment: Thank you @OleV.V. then I will remove that part which say it is a bug either the Temporary word

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

> where the seconds and millseconds are 00000 and this is when the parser fails

No, the parser succeeds. Your issue is with *generating* a String, not parsing.

The default `DateTimeFormatter` suppresses zero values in seconds and fractional second, [as documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#toString()).

## Feature, not a bug

Your problem is not in the parsing, but in the generating of a string *after* parsing. Keep in mind that the textual representation of a date-time object is distinct and separate from the object. In other words, a date-time object does not have a “format”.

> [String] --> `parse` --> [LocalDateTime] --> `toString` --> [String]

The documentation for [`LocalDateTime::toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#toString()) clearly says that the shortest possible formatting variation will be used when encountering zero values in the least-significant parts. To quote:

> The output will be one of the following ISO-8601 formats:
>
> uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm
>
> uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss
>
> uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS
>
> uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS
>
> uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS
>
> The format used will be the shortest that outputs the full value of the time where the omitted parts are implied to be zero.

### Examples

Regarding two examples shown in [the accepted Answer by YCF_L](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49967274/642706)…

> 20180301091600001        result is      2018-03-01T09:16:00.001

In that example, the least-significant part (millisecond) has a non-zero value, so it is represented in the result.

> 2018030100000000         result is      2018-03-01T00:00

In that example, the least significant parts of hour, minute, second, milliseconds, microseconds, and nanoseconds are all zero. So their display is suppressed, except for hours and minutes as the documentation promises that year-minute is always displayed.

So both of your examples work as documented; feature, not a bug.

## Solution

The solution is to not use the default formatter provided in the `toString` method. Instead, use another formatter. For example, use the same custom formatter you defined for parsing.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS" );
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "20180301091600000" , f );

String outputDefault = ldt.toString();
String outputCustom = ldt.format( f );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "outputDefault: " + outputDefault );
System.out.println( "outputCustom: " + outputCustom );
```

> outputDefault: 2018-03-01T09:16
>
> outputCustom: 20180301091600000

The Question asks:

> How can I fix it to make it print 2018-03-01T09:16:00.000 instead of 2018-03-01T09:16 ?

Specify a custom formatter instead of the default formatter.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSS") ; 
String output = ldt.format( f ) ;
```

But keep in mind your generated String will suppress display of any microseconds or nanoseconds in the `LocalDateTime` object.

Comment: Hi @Basil Bourque but the OP want to produce `2018-03-01T09:16:00:000` so i think your solution is not what the OP want exactly no?

Comment: @YCF_L The desired output is irrelevant - The point of the Question (see the title) is thinking that the parser failed to parse and omitted data. But no, the code in Question implicitly calls `toString` which uses a formatter that suppresses zero values in seconds and fractional-second. So **the premise of the Question is wrong**. As for the desired format, that is a side-issue, and has been handled in hundreds, if not thousands, of existing Questions and Answers. I suppose I could show such formatting code, but that is beside the point, and you already did a good job of that.

Comment: You are a hero @Basil read the report I just receive it https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8202144 it is the same as you already mention in your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

@BasilBourque I have a further query on you above answer

I have a date "2023-12-10T00:00:00.000" when we parse this in OffsetDateTime
The parsed OffsetDateTime object never have second and nanoseconds. can we somehow add seconds and nanos into OffsetDateTime object as well?
Please see the attached code snippet and debug info

```html
private fun parse3(date:String) {
    val ldt: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2023-12-10T00:00:00.000", df)
    val odt = OffsetDateTime.of(ldt, ZoneOffset.of("+07:00"))
    val outputDefault = odt.toString()
    val outputCustom = odt.format(df)

    println( "outputDefault: " + outputDefault)
    println( "outputCustom: " + outputCustom)
}
```

[image]

Comment: What you see is the value of [`OffsetDateTime#toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#toString--) and the documentation clearly mentions: *The format used will be the shortest that outputs the full value of the time where the omitted parts are implied to be zero.* If you want to show zeros for seconds and nanoseconds, you need to get another string using `odt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS"))`. It has been discussed several times on StackOverflow. I recommend you open a few of my or Basil's answers and study them.