# Forcing Java 8 LocalTime toString to report omitted values

Tags: java-8, tostring, localtime

I have the following datetime helper method that converts a UTC-zoned Java 8 `Date` into a datetime string:

```
public static String dateTimeString(Date date) {
    return date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toLocalDateTime().toString();
}
```

The desired result is to *always* have the resultant String be formatted as:

> YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'

Problem is, Java 8 `LocalTime#toString()` **intentionally** strips off time components that are zero. So for instance if I have a `Date` instance that represents **June 8, 2018 at 12:35:00 UTC**. Then the output of this method above is: *2018-06-08'T'12:35'Z'*. Whereas I want it to contain any zeroed-out second/minute/hour components (e.g. *2018-06-08'T'12:35:00'Z'*).

**Any ideas?**

Comment: Obviously, you could create your own DateTimeFormat that formats it like this except without omission. I have no other idea.

Comment: I would accept that as a solution @DreamspacePresident (+1) -- any ideas on what that code would look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: DateTimeFormatter fail to parse time string when seconds and milliseconds are all 0s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49967139/java-datetimeformatter-fail-to-parse-time-string-when-seconds-and-milliseconds)

Comment: Thanks @OleV.V. (+1) however the accepted answer to that question uses `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSS")` which is not UTC-zoned.

Comment: Ok, hotmeatballsoup, I posted it with code as an answer.

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup Too bad you accepted a different answer, even though it came half an hour after mine. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private static DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");

public static String dateTimeString(Date date) {
    return date.toInstant().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(formatter);
}
```

Just use a fixed format pattern string to get your desired format. Let’s try it:

```
    System.out.println(dateTimeString(new Date(0)));
    System.out.println(dateTimeString(new Date(1_524_560_255_555L)));
```

This prints:

```
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
2018-04-24T08:57:35Z
```

- In the first example hours, minutes *and seconds* are printed even if they are 0.
- In the second example *milliseoncds are omitted*  even when they are non-zero (you see that the milliseconds value I specified ends in 555).

All of this said, the output conforms to the ISO 8601 format no matter if you have `2018-06-08T12:35Z`, `2018-06-08T12:35:00Z` or even `2018-06-08T12:35:00.000000000Z`. So you may want to check once more whether leaving out the second works for your purpose before you take the trouble of defining your own formatter.

**Link:** [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you portray the default output to have its letters enclosed in single quotes when Java's actual output instead looks like **2018-06-08T12:35Z**, but anyway, here's the code that produces it as desired, with no omissions:

```
final LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(2018, 6, 8, 12, 35, 0);

final ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(ldt, ZoneId.of("Z"));

final DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'''T'''HH:mm:ss''X''", Locale.US);

System.err.println(dtf.format(zdt));
```

Output:

```
2018-06-08'T'12:35:00'Z'
```

Personally, I'd probably prefer a format like this, containing the millis, giving time zone information not requiring additional knowledge from the user, and not having imho superfluous characters:

```
FORMAT: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'.'SSS Z"

OUTPUT: 2018-06-08 12:35:12.345 +0200
```

Comment: Thanks @Dreamspace President (+1)! How/where could I format this to be UTC-zoned?

Comment: Best I can do is GMT: Replace **X** in the 4-line code, 3rd line, with **OOOO**, which changes that part of the output from **Z** to **GMT**. The JavaDocs say "GMT+8; GMT+08:00; UTC-08:00" but I was not able to ever produce it to say UTC, it always says GMT.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is no out of the box solution. The simplest way would be to write your own class that extends [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) and override method `public String format(TemporalAccessor temporal)` where you would call the original method and then if needed modify the output String. See the flags 'Z' for formatter. If that flag is present then you will need to modify the original output.

Comment: The `DateTimeFormatter`class is final, you can’t extend (subclass) it. Also just defining your own format pattern string appears to be simpler.

Comment: @Ole V.V. - you are correct, I missed that. Then you can have your own class that will contain DateTimeFormatter class, I.e. Wrapper class. And you can write all the methods of DateTimeFormatter and deligate them to the original ones except `public String format(TemporalAccessor temporal)` where you will need to make modification to the original result as needed. A bit more work but it will do