# Print dates with hours, seconds between 2 dates in JAVA

Tags: java

I'm trying figurate a way to print all dates between for example

```
2018/20/01 15:20:31:001
2018/20/01 19:34:03:001
```

The output I want to see is:

```
2018/20/01 15:20:31:001
2018/20/01 15:20:31:002
2018/20/01 15:20:31:003
2018/20/01 15:20:31:004
2018/20/01 15:20:31:005
2018/20/01 15:20:31:006
...
2018/20/01 19:34:02:999
2018/20/01 19:34:03:001
```

Can anyone help me in that? Because all I could find was solutions without hours, minutes etc. and I really need that.

Comment: Show Your tries. Subject "date in Java" is very wide

Comment: What do you mean with a date? If a date means a day, then there aren't any outputs in the example.

Comment: Please elaborate your question. Explain what output you want to see.

Answer (score 1):

You need a [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to format the date like this.

Then you need two [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html)s: One for the start date, one for the end date.

Now you can create a loop that prints out the start date and then changes it (It's immutable, but you can recycle the variable.) via the date's method [.plusSeconds()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#plusSeconds-long-) to get to the next second (Or do you indeed want millisecond resolution?), print out, rinse and repeat, until the two dates are equal.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49996874/3500521)'s an example for formatting a date with milliseconds.

Comment: I need unfortunately milisecond resolution :((

Comment: @Mavematt Simple - just use ldt.plus(1, ChronoUnit.MILLIS);

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to do this with `java.time`:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/dd/MM HH:mm:ss:SSS");
LocalDateTime dt1 = LocalDateTime.parse("2018/20/01 15:20:31:001", formatter);
LocalDateTime dt2 = LocalDateTime.parse("2018/20/01 19:34:03:001", formatter);
System.out.println(Duration.between(dt1, dt2));
```

It prints:

```
PT4H13M32S
```

4 hours 13 minutes 32 seconds.

To get an output like the one you showed, you can do this:

```
long totalSeconds = Duration.between(dt1, dt2).getSeconds();
for (long i = 0 ; i < totalSeconds * 1000 ; i++) {
    System.out.println(dt1.plus(i, ChronoUnit.MILLIS).format(formatter));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you explain how to use getSeconds in order to print out each time?

Comment: @Mavematt Edited.

Comment: Ohhh :(( But the problem is, I need output in that format      
    2018/20/01 15:20:31:001,
    2018/20/01 15:20:31:002,    2018/20/01 15:20:31:003,
2018/20/01 15:20:31:004,
2018/20/01 15:20:31:005,
2018/20/01 15:20:31:006,
...
2018/20/01 19:34:02:999,
2018/20/01 19:34:03:001

Comment: @Mavematt Edited again.