# Parsing timestamp as LocalDateTime

Tags: java, string, date, formatting, localdate

I want to parse a timestamp in the form of `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` as `LocalDateTime`. When doing so, it strips the seconds if they are `00`.

[As described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49971698/1170330), I need to use a custom formatter

```
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse("2008-10-02T12:30:00");
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");

String dateString = date.toString();
String dateFormatted = date.format(f);

System.out.println(dateString); // 2008-10-02T12:30
```

This one works, but it returns a `String`:

```
System.out.println(dateFormatted); // 2008-10-02T12:30:00
```

When I parse the string to `LocalDateTime` it strips the `00` again:

```
LocalDateTime dateLDT = LocalDateTime.parse(dateFormatted, f);
System.out.println(dateLDT); // 2008-10-02T12:30
```

So how can I parse a date as `LocalDateTime`, instead of `String`, and keep the `00` at the end?

Comment: You need to parse `dateFormatted`, where is the problem?  You cannot *parse* a `LocalDateTime`, you can only ever parse `String`s - and that `String`s have to have the correct format. And how a date chooses to overload its `toString` method should not matter to you since you always have to use a formatter to get any proper format.

Comment: I believe that [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) provides for optional elements, but you'll need to play around with it

Comment: Seems you meant to print and parse `dateFormatted`, **not** `dateString`

Comment: @ernest_k: Please see my update. It strips the 00-es again.

Comment: **That Does Not Matter** - I repeat what I already said: "how a date chooses to overload its toString method should not matter to you since you always have to use a formatter to get any proper format."

Comment: @luk2302: The output of a formatter is a String, but I need a LocalDateTime.

Comment: `LocalDateTime` internally uses a format that we’re not concerned about, and it doesn’t make sense to talk about whether it has or hasn’t seconds in it. Only its `toString` method produced a string without seconds if seconds and fraction of seconds are zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should expect a difference in output between

```
LocalDateTime dateLDT = LocalDateTime.parse(dateFormatted, f);
System.out.println(dateLDT);
```

And

```
System.out.println(dateLDT.format(f)) //or f.format(dateLDT)
```

`System.out.println(dateLDT);` prints the value of `dateLDT.toString()`, which is not expected to produce the same output as your pattern.

When you look at `LocalDateTime.toString()`, you'll see that it delegates the time part to `LocalTime.toString()`, which prints seconds conditionally:

```
public String toString() {
    ...
    if (secondValue > 0 || nanoValue > 0) {
        buf.append(secondValue < 10 ? ":0" : ":").append(secondValue);
        ...
        }
    }
    return buf.toString();
}
```

It simply omits the seconds field if its value is `0`.

What you need to do in this case is always use a `DateTimeFormatter` to format your date if you have to be certain about the output/input format.

Comment: Hi @ernest_k I have a timestamp [ 2020-08-26T11:41:25.310 ]. How to extract date from it? I can use regex but is there an inbuilt method for it in new Java.time?

Comment: @MdBasha - `LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-26T11:41:25.310").toLocalDate()` should return `2020-08-26` (as a `LocalDate` object). Just note that it works without a custom pattern because `2020-08-26T11:41:25.310` is in the default format used by `LocalDateTime`

Comment: Okay understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Every date object has seconds. Wether or not it chooses to display them with the default `toString` implementation does not matter. *If* you want a specific format you always need to use a formatter.

If you want to see the seconds, either use a proper formatter or set a breakpoint and inspect the object. Looking at *any* `toString` implementation of *anything* is never guaranteed to display anything useful or represent the actual object state. The object could just return a random date string.

For now you can just use `date`, it is perfectly fine, it has seconds.