# How to properly format LocalTime to HH:MM?

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I am trying to use a getter to get the LocalTime in `HH:mm` anytime it is called. As it stands right now it is:

```py
private LocalTime time;

public LocalTime getTime() {
    return time;
}
```

I would like for it to return the time in `HH:mm`, because as it stands right now it is `HH:mm:SS.s`. I am trying to mess with date time formatter, but I can't figure it out. Here is what I have:

```java
private LocalTime time;

public LocalTime getTime() {
   DateTimeFormatter formatDateTime = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
   LocalTime localFormattedTime = LocalTime.parse(time, formatDateTime);
   return localFormattedTime;
}
```

Comment: Are you want to format LocalTime data  into String ?

Comment: Does it need to be formatted into a String to work with DateTimeFormatter? I tried formatting it into a String originally and couldn't get that to work either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing timestamp as LocalDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54941872/parsing-timestamp-as-localdatetime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `LocalTime` not have date part it have only the time part
2. You can't have a specific format for `LocalDate`, `LocalTime`, `LocalDateTime`, it use a standard format and you can't change it.
3. If you want a specific format then you have to use String and not `LocalDate`, `LocalTime`, `LocalDateTime`.

Answer (score 3):

The [answer by YCF_L](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63022418/10819573) is correct and to-the-point. The reason why I have written this answer is I have seen similar kind of questions (why my date/time is not being printed in a custom way) being asked every now and then.

Note that `LocalDate`, `LocalTime`, `LocalDateTime` etc. each have their own `toString()`implementation and no matter what you do, whenever you print their object, their `toString()` method will be called and thus always their default representation will be printed. If you want these objects to be printed in a custom way, you have two options:

1. You get their elements (e.g. year, month and day from an object of `LocalDate`) and print them by arranging in your custom way.
2. Use a formatter class e.g. (the modern `DateTimeFormatter` or the legacy `SimpleDateFormat`) and get a string representing the date/time object in a custom way.

To make your code reusable and clean, you prefer the second approach.

The following example illustrates the same:

```
class Name {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Name() {
        firstName = "";
        lastName = "";
    }

    public Name(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
}

class NameFormatter {
    // Returns a name (e.g. First Last) as F. Last
    public static String patternIntialsLast(Name name) {
        if (name.getFirstName().length() > 1) {
            return name.getFirstName().charAt(0) + ". " + name.getLastName();
        }
        return name.toString();
    }

    // Returns a name (e.g. First Last) as Last F.
    public static String patternLastInitials(Name name) {
        if (name.getFirstName().length() > 1) {
            return name.getLastName() + " " + name.getFirstName().charAt(0) + ".";
        }
        return name.toString();
    }

    // Returns a name (e.g. First Last) as Last First
    public static String patternLastIFirst(Name name) {
        return name.getLastName() + ", " + name.getFirstName();
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Name name = new Name("Foo", "Bar");
        System.out.println("Default format:");
        System.out.println(name);// It will always print what name.toString() returns

        // If you want to print name in different formats use NameFormatter e.g.
        System.out.println("\nIn custom formats:");
        String strName1 = NameFormatter.patternIntialsLast(name);
        System.out.println(strName1);

        String strName2 = NameFormatter.patternLastIFirst(name);
        System.out.println(strName2);

        String strName3 = NameFormatter.patternLastInitials(name);
        System.out.println(strName3);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Default format:
Foo Bar

In custom formats:
F. Bar
Bar, Foo
Bar F.
```

Now, go through the [answer by YCF_L](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63022418/10819573) again and this time, you know that you have to implement your method as follows:

```
public String getTime() {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
    return formatter.format(ldt);
}
```

**A quick demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    // Now
    static LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(), LocalTime.now());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getTime());
    }

    public static String getTime() {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
        return formatter.format(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
22:23
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this. I d

```html
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH.mm");
 
LocalTime today = LocalTime.now();
 
String timeString = today.format(formatter);    //12.38
```

Comment: Thanks, I could easily adapt this to Scala and it worked nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
String localTimeString = "23:59:59";
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
try {
    TemporalAccessor ta = dtf.parse(localTimeString);
    LocalTime lt = LocalTime.from(ta);
    LOGGER.info("lt: {}", lt);
} catch (RuntimeException re) {
    LOGGER.error("Unable to parse local time string: [{}]", localTimeString, re);
}
```

Consult the Java documentation on [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for details on the patterns it supports.

You can also use the DateTimeFormatter to format a LocalTime back into string form, like this:

```
String localTimeAsString = dtf.format(lt)
LOGGER.info("LocalTime as string: {}", localTimeAsString);
```