# Zero seconds are not printed in spite of the formatter pattern (java.time)

Tags: java, datetime, time, datetime-format, java-time

I'm converting 12-hour style time to 24-hour.
The problem is that when seconds are "00" they are not printed in spite of the formatter pattern.
Why is this happening and how to print zero seconds?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String time_1 = "07:05:40PM";
        String time_2 = "07:05:00PM";

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ssa");

        System.out.println("time_1 " + LocalTime.parse(time_1, formatter));
        System.out.println("time_2 " + LocalTime.parse(time_2, formatter));
    }
```

The output is:

```
time_1 19:05:40
time_2 19:05
```

Comment: Can you refer this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49967139/java-datetimeformatter-fail-to-parse-time-string-when-seconds-and-milliseconds

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder#parseCaseInsensitive`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#parseCaseInsensitive--) to parse the time in case-insensitive manner. Also, make sure to use the appropriate format to print the time.

Do it as

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;

public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        String time_1 = "07:05:40PM";
        String time_2 = "07:05:00PM";

        // Format to parse input time-string
        DateTimeFormatter formatter1 = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .parseCaseInsensitive()
                .appendPattern("hh:mm:ssa")
                .toFormatter();

        // 24-hour format
        DateTimeFormatter formatter2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");

        System.out.println("time_1 " + LocalTime.parse(time_1, formatter1));
        System.out.println("time_2 " + LocalTime.parse(time_2, formatter1));
        System.out.println("time_2 " + formatter1.format(LocalTime.parse(time_2, formatter1)));
        System.out.println("time_2 " + formatter2.format(LocalTime.parse(time_2, formatter1)));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
time_1 19:05:40
time_2 19:05
time_2 07:05:00pm
time_2 19:05:00
```

Comment: The OP want to print `time_2 19:05:00`

Comment: This is same as OP's output

Comment: @YCF_L - Updated the answer to include this format as well.